# Did Gary Taubes prove that cholesterol levels between 200 mg/dl and 240 mg/dl are normal and healthy?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, cholesterol

I am now holding the original, Polish edition book called "The Hidden Therapies - What your doctor won't tell you" authored by Jerzy Zięba, who is widely considered to be a quack by medical authorities in my country. Nevertheless, the sheer amount of facts (or "facts"?) and research papers cited by Mr. Zięba warrants some closer skeptical attention.

Among many other claims Mr. Zięba says that cholesterol levels between 200 mg/dl and 240 mg/dl are healthy. In particular, he cites Gary Taubes, who in an article titled “The soft science of dietary fat”, published in March 2001 in Science, supposedly proved that:

- No increased risk of mortality in women nor men was associated with cholesterol levels of 200 mg/dl to 240 mg/dl;
- Cholesterol level of 240 mg/dl was associated with a reduced risk of mortality among women from heart diseases.

Did Gary Taubes publish an article claiming these things?

Does this article indeed prove what Mr. Zięba claims it to prove?

The aforementioned claims come from: Ukryte Terapie - Czego lekarz ci nie powie by Jerzy Zięba, vol. 2, pages 107-112.